# Remote GDB Debugger illegal characters in path

Tags: visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging

I'm trying to port an existing linux project that's currently being coded in terminals into visual studio 2015 as a "Console Application (linux)" since IDE's would be verry much helpfull for my team.
The problem is that I cannot compile remotely:
`1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.Common.targets(259,5): error : Illegal characters in path.`

I opened the file, and it is one that's created by visual studio.
this is exactly what's at line 259:
`<Ld Condition="'@(RemoteLink)' != ''"`

To me it doesn't like there's anything wrong with it.
What am I missing?

Comment: I'm getting the same error, additionally, these are the 12 errors that I get: http://i.imgur.com/XiJcQZM.png

Comment: I have tried to compile it through SSH with same linker options and it compiles perfectly, I also have compiled it remotely to a RPi3 perfectly. It's in a VPS running Ubuntu x64 where it gives me these errors

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the linking of the project didn't succeed.

You are probably getting more errors about the link failing.

If the only error you get is "collect2: ld returned -1" or similar, it probably means that the VSlinux couldn't parse the error and convert it to vs format.

This (at least in my case) was caused by one of the additional link inputs not being found.